# Stop datatables from reinstantiating when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

I'm having an issue with my jquery datatable in my angular project reinstantiating inside itself when retrieving the data from a row.

As I have said in another question, for the experienced angular programmers I am aware that using jquery with angular is probably the worst thing a developer can do but as datatables is jquery based its sort of a last resort.

Please see below the function I'm calling when the user clicks the edit button on the image below.

[image: Datatable with edit button]

```
  editMedia(){
  $('#mediaTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', (element) => {


      let data = $('#mediaTable').DataTable().row( element.currentTarget ).data();
      let code = data[0];
      let desc = data[1];
      let type = "";
      if(data[3] = "yes") {
        type = "SMS";
      } else if(data[4] = "yes") {
        type = "Email";
      }

      let message = data[5];
      this.open(code,desc,type,message);


    }
    );

  }
```

I think the Datatable gets reinstanciated when the .DataTable() function is called but no idea how to prevent this.

Please see below an image with the result.

[image]

I think the parts hightlighted in red are the original table and the part highlighted in blue is the table that has been reinstanciated inside.

From research, I tried the following line of code to hide the reinstanciated DataTable but this did not work.

```
$("#mediaTabe").wrap("<div style='display:none;'></div>");
```

Any help/advice on how to stop this would be much appreciated and thanks in advance for yor suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to use ngx-datatables in angular instead of jquery datatables. With ngx-datatables there are proper ways of getting the row data rather than using a messy jquery function as shown in my question.

For a working example of ngx-datatables please click on this link [Ngx-Datatables example on github](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/).

Any questions or if you need further direction on how to use ngx-datatables feel free to ping a comment below and I try and examples via a simple project.

Thanks